# Select2 — Making a custom select element using select2’s amd.require api

Tags: jquery-select2

I am trying to create a custom select2 dropdown element that will:

- have a search field
- will close once an option is selected
- will not flip its position relative to the element that opens/closes the dropdown (i.e. that pane with the arrow down that you click)

Basically, I love the default behavior of select2 apart from that position flipping when the dropdown tries to adjust to the visible area below the select2 element. I want select2 to **always** open downwards. So after searching that's the only solution I could find (using the latest version of select2, which at the moment is 4.0.1):

```
        $.fn.select2.amd.require([
            'select2/utils',
            'select2/dropdown',
            'select2/dropdown/attachContainer',
            'select2/dropdown/closeOnSelect',
            'select2/dropdown/search'
        ], function (Utils, DropdownAdapter, AttachContainer, CloseOnSelect, DropdownSearch) {

            CustomAdapter = Utils.Decorate(
                Utils.Decorate(
                    Utils.Decorate(
                        DropdownAdapter,
                        DropdownSearch
                    ),
                    CloseOnSelect
                ),
                AttachContainer
            );

            this.select.select2({
                dropdownAdapter: CustomAdapter
            });
        }
```

It almost works. But now I don't have a cursor blinking in the search field when I open the dropdown. Clicking on the search field also won't show the cursor, although typed characters will show up in the search field, and the search itself works.

This absense of a visual cue for the user that he can start typing is incredibly annoying, but I can't figure out how to solve it. Could you help me? Or, failing that, maybe you know of a way to prevent this flipping behavior without ugly hacks and without re-building select2 on the fly?

**UPDATE:** Ok, I think there must be some deeper underlying problem on my side, because this absence of focus on the search field is happening even when using a normal full-featured select2.

Comment: If you could reproduce this in a jsbin or stack snippet that would make it easier to debug the issue.

Comment: Hey @KevinBrown! That whole issue was totally my mistake. Or maybe some weird error of my Require.js. It went away after restart. Everything is working now. I don't know whether I should delete my question after this or just leave it as it is.